# Are these ahadith stating that there are seven Earths?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

> "Whoever usurps even one span of land of somebody, its depth through the seven earths will be collared to his neck." (Saheeh Al-Bukhari, ‘Book of Oppression.’; [sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/14))
>
> "Whoever takes a piece of land of others unjustly, he will sink down the seven earths on the Day of Resurrection." (Saheeh Al-Bukhari, ‘Book of Oppression.’; [sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/15))
>
> The Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said that the Prophet Nooh (Noah)  may  Allaah  exalt  his  mention told his son: "I command you to stick to Laa ilaaha illallaah because if the seven heavens and the seven earths were put in one side of a scale and Laa ilaaha illallaah is put on the other side, Laa ilaaha illallaah will outweigh them."

Are these ahadith stating that there are seven Earths?  Many scholars say this, as I have heard.  Or are they saying that the Earth has seven layers? Some scholars say this, as I have heard.

Comment: see duplicate questions, linked at right column, for other answers

Answer (score 3):

Well what do you expect for an answer? You answered your Question already there are 2 different opinions: 7 layers or 7 earths (one could say continents as ibn 'Abbas described them being separated by a sea) with god's creatures on it and according to Imam [al-Qurtubi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=65&ayano=12) in his tafsir of Verse ([65:12](http://legacy.quran.com/65/12)) the last one could be stronger as there are this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/154) and [this](http://sunnah.com/urn/743370) with a tafsir of ([57:3](http://legacy.quran.com/57/3)) in Jami' at-Tirmidhi ! which apparently support it.

See also [tafsir ibn Kathir](http://www.quran4u.com/Tafsir%20Ibn%20Kathir/065%20Talaq.htm).

And Allah knows best!