# What are the 7 earths that is referred to in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, tafseer

***Qur'an “It is Allah Who has created seven heavens and of the earth the like thereof”***

What are these 7 Earths that are referred to in the Noble Qur'an? What do the scholars say about this?

Comment: This question has already an answer of mine due to the fact that i'm only online via my mobilefon i can't mark it as a duplicate.!

Comment: I suppose [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28424/hadith-about-the-earths) is the post @Medi1Saif means.